# Outlook proxy inside vpn

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, outlook, cisco

Usually in the office or at home I have to use the Cisco VPN to get in the company network.
Now, the problem. 
For some reason when I'm in the VPN, outlook tries to use the proxy associated with the IE.
I have configured the proxy in the outlook configuration (Account Settings --> More Settings --> Connection --> Exchange Proxy Settings), but inside the vpn it tries to use the IE proxy.
There is any program that could control the proxy in OS level?
I have the foxy proxy for Firefox, but I have to change manually the settings in the IE.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. I'm using windows 7 64bit, outlook 2013 and the classic Cisco VPN Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention *why* you consider this a problem?

"Exchange Proxy Settings" doesn't mean what you think it does-- in this context "Exchange Proxy" refers to the gateway that converts between the native Exchange sync protocol and RPC-over-HTTPS. It isn't related to a traditional HTTP proxy server.

In Windows, the IE proxy settings basically *are* the OS proxy settings. If you'd like to change them, there are many ways. Setproxy.exe from http://bayden.com/other/ is how I do it, but there are tons of alternatives.

Comment: I usually don't use IE.
I use firefox and open the Outlook, so I don't pay attention to the proxy on the IE.

Comment: If you'd like to open the proxy settings without going through IE, open the system control panel and open the Internet Settings or Internet Options Control Panel. Or Start > Run > `inetcpl.cpl`